# Cannot select radio button that was added by JavaScript in watir

Tags: html, jquery, internet-explorer, watir

This was added to the page later with jQuery:

```
<input name="pdfRadio" id="pdfRadioNo0" value="0" type="radio">
```

This code:

```
radio_id = "pdfRadioNo0"
ie.radio(:id, radio_id).set()
```

does not set it but returns an error message:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using {:id=>"pdfRadioNo0"}
```

Does watir also find radio butons that were added later?

This is windows 32bit XP SP 3 , IE 7, watir 1.6.5, ruby 1.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it is a timing issue.

I was trying to access the element in watir before it was created.

This code now works:

```
radio_id = "pdfRadioNo0"
Watir::Waiter.wait_until{ie.radio(:id, radio_id).exists?} 
ie.radio(:id, radio_id).set()
```

I found the solution in this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/2dce70e313027d05

Comment: Karl, could you please mark your answer as correct, so that the question no longer looks like it was unanswered?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this happened. Sometimes there is a forced delay. Thank you for reminding - karlthorwald - aka